# How can I refer to the currently open file in Vim?

Tags: vim

In vim, how can I refer to the file that I am currently editing? I want to be able to map a key to run `:!java` on the file that I am currently working on.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `%` to refer to the current buffer's filename; modifiers (cp. `:help filename-modifiers`) like `:p` can create a full absolute path, or shave off an extension.

Note that a solution with `!java` will only work with simple classes in the default package, the use of which is *not* recommended. Unless you want this just for quick prototyping and throwaway stuff, I'd suggest you use a build system like *Ant* or *Maven*, and define a target like *run* there. Then, with the proper `'makeprg'` set in Vim, you can launch your application (also when not directly editing the Java file containing the main class) via

```
:make run
```